# Should I commit my wrangler.toml file with KV namespace values present?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-kv

I've created an API using Cloudflare Workers and it uses their KV service. The KV namespaces are defined in the `wrangler.toml` file but I'm unsure if it is safe to commit that file with the `kv_namespaces` values present. I've used the wrangler secrets for API keys but since these aren't environment variables I'm not sure how I should handle them.

What is the correct way to handle pushing a `wrangler.toml` file to a git repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The namespace ID in `wrangler.toml` is not a secret. When you publish the worker, Cloudflare will authenticate that your account actually owns the namespace, and will not permit the publish otherwise. So, it's safe to commit to git.

Comment: But won't that be weird to deal with for potential users of your code? I understand it is safe to do, but is that the best practise?

Comment: @lia07 Yes, if you're sharing your code with the intent that different people may deploy it to different accounts, it's weird. You may need to provide them some sort of script to generate wrangler.toml from a template? This is something we (Cloudflare) would also like to find a general solution for but haven't come up with anything yet.